# Logging in and calling normal API Routes does not work with websockets

Tags: websocket, nestjs, passport.js

I have an issue with the authentication process of a websocket route.
I'm using PassportJS with 'local' strategy.
Logging in and calling normal API Routes are perfectly working with @AuthenticatedGuard,
**but not** on websockets

On the Websocket Route, it is throwing following error:

> ERROR [WsExceptionsHandler] request.isAuthenticated is not a function
> TypeError: request.isAuthenticated is not a function

This is my setup:

Example normal working API Route
test.controller.ts

```
@UseGuards(AuthenticatedGuard)
  @Get(':id')
  async findOne(
    @Param('id') id: string,
    @Req() req: any,
    @Res() res: Response,
  ) {
    return res.json(
      await this.testService.findOne(+id),
    );
  }
```

**Websocket Route**
messages.gateway.ts

```
@UseGuards(AuthenticatedGuard)
  @SubscribeMessage('findAllMessages')
  async findAll(
    @ConnectedSocket() client: Socket,
    @MessageBody() findAllMessages: findAllMessages,
    @Req() req: any,
  ) {
    console.log(req);
    //return this.messagesService.findAll(chatroomid);
    const user = await this.messagesService.checkCurrentSessionString(
      req.handshake.headers.cookie,
    );
    if (req.user.userid != undefined) {
      return await this.messagesService.findAll(findAllMessages, user.userid);
    } else client.disconnect(true);
    throw new UnauthorizedException({
      statusCode: 401,
      message: 'Bitte logge dich erst ein',
    });
  }
```

authenticated.guard.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate {
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return request.isAuthenticated();
  }
}
```

Seems like the session is not valid for the websocket routes?

Comment: The `context.switchToHttp()` doesn't work correctly on websockets because websockets don't have the same context as HTTP requests. You need to find a different way to get the "request". I don't believe `request.isAuthenticated()` will work in a websocket context

Comment: So, what do you recommend to do? Creating another ws-authenticated.guard.ts file but instead of `switchToHttp()`, set `switchToWs()`?